# QField Cloud-PostgreSQL, Cloud not syncing back to PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I am trying to set up a project with QField Cloud where when you get back to the office and hit sync on the phone/tablet it goes to our PostGIS database. I have gone through the workflow in the Advanced setup in the documentation, but have had no luck. I was wondering if I was missing something. I have the credentials saved in the project, am using offline editing, and when it makes the "Project_Name(QFieldCloud)" it puts everything into a geopackage, uploads and gives me the green light. Then when I collect information and hit sync nothing happens on the PostgreSQL side. It will sync back to the "Project_Name(QFieldCloud)" but that does not help me as I would like it to just go to the PostgreSQL database and not the geopackage.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this answer on the github.

https://github.com/opengisch/QField/discussions/2508#discussioncomment-2322119

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).